How to Properly Manage Service Destruction in Angular with Route-Level Providers?
I'm working on an Angular project where I'm lazy loading a module and providing multiple services at the route level. My expectation was that these services would be destroyed when the user navigates away from the route. However, I'm observing that the services are not being destroyed, and their instances persist in memory.
Here is a simplified version of my module and route configuration:
{
   path: 'test-page',
   loadChildren: () => import('lazy-loaded-module-path').then((m) => m. LazyLoadedModule)
}

Module:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainPage,
        providers: [
          MyService,
        ]
      }
    ])
  ]
})
export class LazyLoadedModule {}

Service:
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
  ) {
    console.log('MY SERVICE IS CREATED')
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('MY SERVICE IS DESTROYED')
  }
}


https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37095

@Chellappan good conversation. They just didn't mention the route providers :)

there is workaround for router level providers:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37095#issuecomment-2080175437

Just use the providers array of the module, the destroy will happen, you need to add it to the providers array, of the module!
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainPage,
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [ // <-changed here
     MyService, // <-changed here
  ] // <-changed here
})
export class LazyLoadedModule {}


From angular documentation:
https://angular.io/api/router/Route#providers
This one as well: https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-route-providers

@Milos sorry I am outdated, changed it! thanks!

No problem, now you are updated :)
